# CakePHP3 - MySQL Cyrillic symbols

Tags: mysql, cakephp, encoding, cakephp-3.0, cyrillic

I have CakePHP3 application using utf-8 encoding. On my local win machine its working fine. But on Linux server cyrillic symbols are not correctly recorded in database, something like this - РћРїР°Р°Р°. Browser output in general is ok, except some symbols like “И” which are displayed like this “�?”. When I type cyrillic symbols directly in my database tables, the browser output is ��������.

I noticed that default_charset = “cp1251” in php.ini and changed it to empty string and "utf-8", but in both cases with no success.
I also tried database tables with utf8_general_ci and utf8mb4_general_ci collation, but and this didn’t help.

In my config/app.php is specified UTF-8 encoding, also in html head

`'Datasources' => [ 'default' => [ ... 'encoding' => 'utf8'...
 'App' => [ 'namespace' => 'App', 'encoding' => 'UTF-8'…`

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`

My server environment: PHP 5.5.14, MySQL version: 5.5.40-cll

I tried to read/write in db with my simple php scrip (outside of CakePHP app) using PDO driver, and it works great and no problem with Cyrillic at all.

I have no idea where else to looking for.

Comment: you asked **`Same`** question yesterday too !!

Comment: Yes, but I deleted it and posted again. Yesterday I’ve got an error not related with the problem in question and this causes confusion.